# Windows 11 freezes, wont let me get task manager

Tags: windows, freeze, windows-11, windows-11-preview

So I got Beta windows 11 via insider program.
My Windows 11 freezes randomly and won't allow me to do anything, I can't even get taskmanager or click on any window(minimize, maximize, close). The cursor movement is functional but that's it, I cant use any shortcut to get taskmanager, new explorer or app or anything else. I always have to force a reboot to fix it since letting it sit for a while won't solve the issue, I can't get task manager, I tried mashing click button to try to make explorer crash and restart but it doesn't work either.

Has anyone else faced this issue? Is there a way to fix it or get around it?

I have a decent PC with i7 9th gen processor and 16 gb ram, OS runs on 256 GB SSD and this issue happens randomly when I an not even don't any heavy stuff

EDIT: I have reverted back to windows 10 since windows 11 beta was highly unstable and was affecting productivity

Comment: Sounds like you will have to perform an in-place repair install of Windows 11 21H2. I would immediately get off the Insider Preview build for stability

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I moved from beta to release preview channel. I would see if the same persists for the next few days, if it does I would revert back to windows 10

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author ultimately ended up reverting back to Windows 10 to resolve their issue